# Segmentation fault usint semaphores to synchronize 3 threads in C

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, ubuntu, semaphore

I'm using semaphores to synchronize 3 threads in c in order to print a sequence like `aabcaabcaabc` but my code gives segmentation error in Linux.

I don't see what's wrong with my code, I have made 3 semaphores, one for each thread and syncing them in a way that thread 1 prints `aa` and thread 2 prints `b` and so on.

What can I do to make it work?

```
#include<pthread.h>
#include<semaphore.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
sem_t* sem1;
sem_t* sem2;
sem_t* sem3;


void* printA(void* a)
{
    sem_wait(sem2);
    printf("a");
    printf("a");
    sem_post(sem2);
}

void* printB(void* a)
{
    sem_wait(sem2);
    printf("b");
    sem_post(sem3);
}

void* printC(void* a)
{

    sem_wait(sem3);
    printf("c");
    sem_post(sem1);

}

int main()
{

  sem_init(sem1, 0, 1);
  sem_init(sem2, 0, 0);
  sem_init(sem3, 0, 0);

  pthread_t thread1;
  pthread_t thread2;
  pthread_t thread3;

  pthread_create(&thread1, NULL, &printA, NULL);
  pthread_create(&thread2, NULL, &printB, NULL);
  pthread_create(&thread3, NULL, &printC, NULL);

  pthread_join(thread1, NULL);
  pthread_join(thread2, NULL);
  pthread_join(thread3, NULL);

  sem_destroy(sem1);
  sem_destroy(sem2);
  sem_destroy(sem3);
}
```

Comment: Asking for tool recommendations is off topic on SO - deleted that part of your question.  If using the GNU toolchain, you are likely to use GDB, for CLANG then LLDB.  There are any number of  "user friendly" visual tools (often integrated in an IDE) that use GDB and/or LLDB under the hood (because both are somewhat  _user hostile_).  It is however a matter of opinion - so off topic for that reason too.

Comment: Oops, I had no idea! I'm new here. Thanks though!

Comment: Both printA and printB wait for sem2. No thread waits for sem1.

Comment: 'sem_init(sem1, 0, 1);' cannot initialize sem1.  Try sem_init(&sem1, 0, 1);

Comment: It works now that I changed the sem_wait(sem2) in printA to sem1. It was a typo and very frustrating. Thanks!

Comment: Oh good..now maybe someone can explain to me how it can work:)

Comment: I mean, how come sem1,2,3 are not all null?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running your code in a [debugger](https://onlinegdb.com/YW3OrkEvw) reveals the location of the seg-fault.  With *backtrace* line 41 or main.c (`sem_init(sem1, 0, 1);`).

```
Reading symbols from a.out...done.
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/a.out 
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".

Breakpoint 1, main () at main.c:41
41        sem_init(sem1, 0, 1);
(gdb) next

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
__new_sem_init (sem=0x0, pshared=0, value=1) at sem_init.c:44
44      sem_init.c: No such file or directory.
(gdb) bt
#0  __new_sem_init (sem=0x0, pshared=0, value=1) at sem_init.c:44
#1  0x00000000004008a6 in main () at main.c:41
```

The issue is that `sem1` is an initialised pointer.  You need to pass a pointer to an instantiated `sem_t` object.

```
sem_t sem1;
sem_t sem2;
sem_t sem3;
```

Then:

```
  sem_init( &sem1, 0, 1);
  sem_init( &sem2, 0, 0);
  sem_init( &sem3, 0, 0);
```

and change `sem1` to `&sem1` etc. elsewhere of course.

Note that while that stops your code from seg-faulting, it hangs because neither thread waits on `sem1`.  Probably `printA()` should wait on `sem1` rather then `sem2`.

Comment: Yes, I did correct that and it's working now. Appreciate it!